# How to Apply transformation to Polygon object in Java

Tags: java, casting, transform, polygon, shapes

i have made a transform and rendered a Polygon object with it(mesh is of type Polygon):

```
    at.setToTranslation(gameObject.position.x, gameObject.position.y);
    at.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotation));
    at.scale(scale, scale);
    g2d.setTransform(at);
    g2d.fillPolygon(mesh);
```

now i want to return the exact mesh i rendered so that i can do collision checks on it. only problem is that if i return mesh it returns the un-transformed mesh. so i tried setting the transform to the Polygon object (mesh) like so:

```
    mesh = (Polygon)at.createTransformedShape(mesh);
```

but unfortunately at.createTransformedShape() returns a Shape that can only be casted to Path2D.Double. so if anyone knows how to convert Path2D.Double to Polygon or knows another way to set the transformations to the mesh please please help.

Comment: You should specify the language you're using (as a tag) and presumably also the library you're using. It looks like Java + Swing, but many languages look somewhat like Java.

Comment: yes java. the objects are java.awt.geom.AffineTransform and java.awt.Polygon

Comment: I'd say AffineTransform doesn't know how to turn polygons into polygons, so `createTransformedShape` isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `AffineTransform#createTransformedShape` doesn't provide the desired result for `Polygon`s (as it seems to be the case), you can split the `Polygon` into `Point`s, transform each `Point` and combine into a new `Polygon`. Try:

```
//Polygon mesh
//AffineTransform at

int[] x = mesh.xpoints;
int[] y = mesh.ypoints;
int[] rx = new int[x.length];
int[] ry = new int[y.length];

for(int i=0; i<mesh.npoints; i++){
  Point2d p = new Point2d.Double(x[i], y[i]);
  at.transform(p,p);
  rx[i]=p.x;
  ry[i]=p.y;
}

mesh = new Polygon(rx, ry, mesh.npoints)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but you code doesn't work for some reason. the mesh collision works as if the polygons are not rotated.

Comment: i'm using java.awt.geom.AffineTransform and then my collision check goes like this:

Comment: for(int i=0; i<target.mesh.npoints; i++) 
   if(mesh.contains(target.mesh.xpoints[i], target.mesh.ypoints[i]))
     return true;
   return false;

Comment: target is recieved as a parameter and is an object of the same class

Comment: What is the AffineTransform you're trying to apply? Is it set correctly?

Comment: it's set like this: at = new AffineTransform(); and then at.setToTranslation(gameObject.position.x, gameObject.position.y);
        at.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotation));
        at.scale(scale, scale);

Comment: If `rotation` is already in radians, `Math.toRadians(rotation)` will produce incorrect results (very small amount of rotation)

Comment: it's not the problem since drawing the transformed mesh is working and the results are fine. my only problem is the collision detection it stays as if the mesh isn't rotatoed. if you know of an algorithem to rotate and scale polygons with out transforms i think that would be a good solution since AffineTransforms seem to be a half-way solution to rotating a polygon

Comment: The transformation matrix for a rotation is `[[cos(th),sin(th)],[-sin(th),cos(th)]]`

Comment: Nvm. your solution was correct i just wasn't apply it correctly. sorry and thanks